# Python Requests gives a different status code compared to website call

Tags: python, python-requests

I use Requests and some URL's give a different response code than a call with the same URL in a browser.

For example:

```
import requests
req = requests.get('http://www.jordaaninfo.nl')
responsecode = req.status_code
# responsecode == 500
```

gives a responsecode 500 while the page http://www.jordaaninfo.nl is available via Chrome/FF/Safari.

Thanks,
Niels

Comment: Please don't include the chevrons from the prompt.

Comment: This has already been asked several times here. Please search for answers before asking.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost It's very useful if you can link to a duplicate.

Comment: @Marcin Usually I do but I'm kind of tired doing this, especially as others do nothing and instead jump to answer to gain invaluable reputation...

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Me too. It is for that reason that there is a close option on grounds of duplication. Even if you are not able to vote to close, you can put the link in a comment, and raise a flag for an administrator.

Comment: @marcin & PiotrDobrogost Sorry for that. Understand the problem, but I did multiple searches and couldn't find anything helpful concerning this specific problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Firefox the 500 status code also occurs for www.jordaaninfo.nl, but the page is displayed anyway. This can be seen in the Net tab of Firebug. 
My Chromium browser on Linux gets a 200 OK.

The problem (and solution) is in the Accept-Language header in the request.
Apparently, the server has special needs in this respect ;-)

The problem and solution can be demonstrated with wget:

```
$ wget 'http://www.jordaaninfo.nl/'
--2012-11-20 23:15:20--  http://www.jordaaninfo.nl/
Resolving www.jordaaninfo.nl... 87.250.155.10
Connecting to www.jordaaninfo.nl|87.250.155.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2012-11-20 23:15:22 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

$ wget --header="Accept-Language: Accept-Language: en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5" 'http://www.jordaaninfo.nl/'
--2012-11-20 23:16:01--  http://www.jordaaninfo.nl/
Resolving www.jordaaninfo.nl... 87.250.155.10
Connecting to www.jordaaninfo.nl|87.250.155.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
....
```

The 500 Error in my Firefox was caused by language 'nl' as first entry in the Accept-Language setting:

```
nl,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,fy;q=0.3 --> 500 ERROR
en,nl;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,fy;q=0.3 --> 200 OK
```

Comment: Thanks vriend. That does the trick. >>> headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en'}
>>> req = requests.get('http://www.jordaaninfo.nl',headers=headers)
>>> req.status_code
    200